# Are user defined types (UDTs) available in an Azure SQL database managed instance?

Tags: azure-sql-database, user-defined-table-type, user-defined-type

Is it possible to create user defined types and user defined table types in an Azure SQL database managed instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-defined types are supported in [Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) except those based on a CLR assembly, which is not supported.